# Use system environment variable in LaunchAnywhere properties .lax file

Tags: java, properties-file, java-launcher

Is there a posibility to use system environment variable in property value of .lax   file?

In this sample I have:

```
lax.nl.env.path=..\\jre\\bin;D:\\TEST\\bin
lax.command.line.args=$CMD_LINE_ARGUMENTS$
```

and I want to use something as

```
lax.nl.env.path=..\\jre\\bin;$MY_SYSTEM_VAR$
lax.command.line.args=$CMD_LINE_ARGUMENTS$
```

where **MY_SYSTEM_VAR** has the value **D:\TEST\bin**. I want to make this lax file configurable from outside of this, at runtime.

[Here](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installanywhere2014/Content/helplibrary/ia_ref_variables_lax_properties.htm) I found a filst of LAX Properties, where is specified a property **lax.nl.env.variable_name** used to access any system environment variable but I don't know how.

Thank you